# Need help understanding this way of animating sprites

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I am using the book "Learning XNA 4.0"

http://codepaste.net/f6w368 is the code

What I am not getting is, the currentFrame.X * frameSize.X. Seeing as how anything mutlipled by 0 = 0. Only other way I think how this works is, when currentFrame++ happens, it becomes 1*75, etc. But this is still a bit fuzzy to me, can someone help me understand this?

The sheetsize is 6 frames by 8 frames. And the sprite size is 75x75. And I am not exactly experienced with Points, so thats what had me somewhat more confused.

Edit: Thanks. I feel kinda stupid, since it's kinda obvious >_>.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bit too general, but maybe this will help.

The top left corner of your animation is `0,0`, so the first sprite will be a rectangle whose top left corner is at `0,0` and whose width and height is 75. The next frame will be a rectangle whose top left corner is at `75,0` and so on. When you multiply the frame number by the frame width, you get the x-coordinate of the sprite for that frame.

This picture might also help you a bit:

[image: Depiction]

I also recommend using `Vector2`s instead of `Point`s, they work pretty much the same, but the `Vector2` has useful operators and methods that make your life easier later on.